# difference between twisted and turned

Tags: vocabulary

> "Three up... two across he muttered. "Right, stand back,
>   Harry." 
>        He tapped the wall three times with the
>   point of his umbrella. 
>        The brick he had touched
>   quivered –– it wriggled –– in the middle, a small hole appeared –– it
>   grew wider and wider –– a second later they were facing an archway
>   large enough even for Hagrid, an archway onto a cobbled street that
>   **twisted and turned out of sight**. 
>        "Welcome," said Hagrid, "to Diagon Alley."  
>  (Harry Potter and the
>   Sorcerer's Stone)

From the context, ‘twist’ seems to mean ‘bend slightly not to out of sight’; ‘turn’ ‘curve enough to be out of sight’. Is it what the two words really mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Twist and turn* is a common collocation.  Semantically, it's a single unit meaning "a number of intricate twists and turns".  It can appear with both words in noun form:

- Twists and turns
- Every twist and turn

Or in various verb forms, meaning "twisting and turning many times, in intricate fashion":

- Twist and turn
- Twists and turns
- Twisted and turned
- Twisting and turning

And so on.  I suggest you not try to analyze the meaning of the two words separately.  Instead, analyze the pair like this:

> ... a cobbled street that [twisted and turned] out of sight.

In other words, as though it's a single verb.